# How to trigger an action based on stale github PR?

Tags: typescript, github, github-actions

I'm aware of the [github actions stale tool](https://github.com/actions/stale) and I can use it to label and close stale PR's.

I'm looking to implement a workflow that would perform some action `dummy_action` if the PR has been stale for `x` days. Is there a way to do that? I looked through the source-code of `actions/stale` and couldn't figure out how it is reading the last PR activity timestamp. Can someone help me point to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code here: https://github.com/actions/stale/blob/87c2b794b9b47a9bec68ae03c01aeb572ffebdb1/src/IssueProcessor.ts#L106

It uses `issue.updated_at`

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "node_id": "MDU6SXNzdWUx",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347",
  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
  "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347/labels{/name}",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347/comments",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347/events",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347",
  "number": 1347,
  "state": "open",
  "title": "Found a bug",
  "body": "I'm having a problem with this.",
  [...]
  "closed_at": null,
  "created_at": "2011-04-22T13:33:48Z",
  "updated_at": "2011-04-22T13:33:48Z",
  [...]
}
```

> **Note:** GitHub's REST API v3 considers every pull request an issue
> https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#get-an-issue